# Work folder in Jboss Fuse

Tags: jbossfuse

What is the work folder in Jboss Fuse?

I had re-deployed camel blueprint project in Jboss Fuse, but new changes are not effected in Jboss Fuse.

Jboss Fuse processing with my previous project deployment.

Comment: what do you mean by "re-deployed"? There are better ways to install bundles than dropping them to `deploy/` dir. Try `install -s mvn:groupId/artifactId/version`. They you can just `update <bundleId>` it when you have newer version in your local maven repository

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with SNAPSHOT artifacts, then "update" command in Karaf with the bundle IDs should do the job (after redeploying with Maven).

As a last resort, JBOSS_FUSE_HOME/data is where everything is stored. By deleting this directory, you would be reseting Fuse to defaults. That is, if you are not using Fuse Fabric.

Answer (score 1):

The first action I can suggest is to uninstall the bundles and restart the instance.

Deleting the entire `JBOSS_FUSE_HOME/data` may fix the problem but you have to stop it first otherwise you can break something. But if you want to keep the previous installed features and settings you can try the following:

1. find out the IDs of the bundles that cannot be updated and uninstall them
2. go to `JBOSS_FUSE_HOME/data/cache/`
3. delete the bundle folders that have the IDs of step 1.
4. delete them from `JBOSS_FUSE_HOME/deploy` folder also if they have been hot deployed
5. Then restart the Fuse instance.
6. When you do **`list`** and if your trouble bundles are there, **`uninstall`** them
7. Finally you can redeploy your bundles and they should work normally.

Sometimes when you do hot deploy and restarting, Fuse can't manage to delete the old caches. To find if you are using a cached version of a bundle use `packages-import` and `packages-export` commands. If you see an older bundle Id then definitely this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem with a single application you don't need to delete data folder.
Open Karaf console and logs in two tabs

Step 1 : **stop bundleID**{ID of bundle that you need to uninstall} (on karaf)
Step 2 : **tailf fuse.log | grep -i "Application context"**(You will see 2 logs )

- **Unpublishing application context OSGi service for bundle {bundleName}**
- **Application context succesfully closed**

**Step 3 : osgi:uninstall bundleId**

Still if you face issue.

Goto FUSE_HOME/data/cache and delete folder with name **bunndle{ID}** where ID is bundle ID that you need to uninstall.

If still issue occurs, please **change the version** of your bundle and then install